# OpenPrinting CUPS | what's difference between cancel vs lprm?

Tags: command-line, bash, printing

```
cancel -a -x

lprm -
```

Both cancels print jobs, but when I should use each one?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12245/181039